# Script to replace matching pattern between file 1 (rev.fasta) and file 2 (necessary_files/index_rev.fasta) IN FILE 1 with information from file 2

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, grep

I'm a molecular biologist who just recently started working with bash and is trying to write a couple of scripts to automate some things that I tipically have to do manually.
I have two files (rev.fasta and index_rev.fasta), looking like this:

```
$ head rev.fasta
>1
bc-1
>2
bc-1
>3
bc-1
>4
bc-1
>5
bc-1
```

```
$ head necessary_files/index_rev.fasta
>rev-bc-1
TGTGTTGAGACCACACAGGCCTCAGTCTCGTGGGCTCGG
>rev-bc-2
GTCTGTCGCCATGGAAAGTCAACTGTCTCGTGGGCTCGG
>rev-bc-3
TTGCTACGGTTGACCATGCAGTTAGTCTCGTGGGCTCGG
>rev-bc-4
AACTTGAGGTATCGTATATTCAATGTCTCGTGGGCTCGG
>rev-bc-5
GCAGGTGGGCATCCGGACCGATATGTCTCGTGGGCTCGG
```

and I want to write bash command(s) that

1. match rev.fasta with sed 's/>rev-//g' necessary_files/index_rev.fasta ;
   like grep or similar
2. substitute the "bc-.*$" match found in rev.fasta (e.g., "bc-1") by the next line of the necessary_files/index_rev.fasta file (e.g., TGTGTTGAGACCACACAGGCCTCAGTCTCGTGGGCTCGG for "bc-1")

The result of this being something like:

```
>1
TGTGTTGAGACCACACAGGCCTCAGTCTCGTGGGCTCGG
>2
TGTGTTGAGACCACACAGGCCTCAGTCTCGTGGGCTCGG
>3
TGTGTTGAGACCACACAGGCCTCAGTCTCGTGGGCTCGG
```

**Note:**
Some information that might be important:
bc- goes from 1 to 16

I have no idea how I can do this. I've tried several things, but I fear it might be more complicated to do than what I'm capable of at the moment. Any ideas?

Comment: are you guaranteed to have a match for each row?

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) output generated by said code

Comment: If the files are will always have matching lines in the same order, you might try `paste`:

    `paste -d'\n' rev.fasta necessary_files/index_rev.fasta`

That will give you extra lines you don't want, but they could be easily removed: `| sed '/>rev/d' | sed '/bc-/d'`

Comment: Given the background you share about yourself, I highly recommend spending the time to learn both `sed` and `awk` thoroughly and in detail; the time investment will likely pay off a hundredfold in your line of work.  Recommended tutorials are here: https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html and https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the problem is that you want to search the fatsa file based on your index file. In my response below the index file is called patterns.txt. I have also changed that file a little to test and demonstrate the process. You can use your own pattern.txt file once you have read this answer.

So here are the assumptions:

```
$ cat fasta
>rev-bc-1
TGTGTTGAGACCACACAGGCCTCAGTCTCGTGGGCTCGG
>rev-bc-2
GTCTGTCGCCATGGAAAGTCAACTGTCTCGTGGGCTCGG
>rev-bc-3
TTGCTACGGTTGACCATGCAGTTAGTCTCGTGGGCTCGG
>rev-bc-4
AACTTGAGGTATCGTATATTCAATGTCTCGTGGGCTCGG
>rev-bc-5
GCAGGTGGGCATCCGGACCGATATGTCTCGTGGGCTCGG

$ cat patterns.txt 
>1
bc-4
>2
bc-2
```

First run this command to extract from fasta file those required by patterns.txt:

```
$ awk '/bc/{print}' patterns.txt | xargs -I{} awk -v q=$(echo {}) '($0 ~ q){getline; print}' fasta
AACTTGAGGTATCGTATATTCAATGTCTCGTGGGCTCGG
GTCTGTCGCCATGGAAAGTCAACTGTCTCGTGGGCTCGG
```

save this output in a temporary file; let's call it fasout

Now run this second command to get the final result:

```
awk '!/bc/{print}' patterns.txt | paste -d '\n' - fasout

>1
AACTTGAGGTATCGTATATTCAATGTCTCGTGGGCTCGG
>2
GTCTGTCGCCATGGAAAGTCAACTGTCTCGTGGGCTCGG
```

Explanation: The first command extracts the lines that contain bc-1, bc-2 etc. from patterns.txt. Those are then piped into the second awk (one at a time) to find the corresponding line, and when found the next line is printed using getline option of awk.

The second command simply merges the pattern.txt file with the fastout such that bc-1, bc-2 etc. lines are replaced by contents of fasout.

There are some caveats that I have not mentioned as I am not sure if this is indeed the solution you want. If so then I will be happy to edit my answer later and include them.